# Replace all escape sequences with non-escaped equivalent strings in java

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I have a string like this:

```
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;ClinicalDocument&gt;rest of CCD here&lt;/ClinicalDocument&gt;]]&gt;
```

I'd like to replace the escape sequences with their non-escaped characters, to end up with:

```
<![CDATA[<ClinicalDocument>rest of CCD here</ClinicalDocument>]]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a non-regex solution.

```
String original = "something";

String[] escapes = new String[]{"&lt;", "&gt;"}; // add more if you need
String[] replace = new String[]{"<", ">"}; // add more if you need

String new = original;

for (int i = 0; i < escapes.length; i++) {
    new = new.replaceAll(escapes[i], replace[i]);
}
```

Sometimes a simple loop is easier to read, understand, and code.

Comment: From a comment of Tomalak: *'And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion.'* (I'm not implying you didn't contribute with your answer, I'm just commenting about the quote which everyone here has seen posted at least 1000000000 times by now...)

Comment: me too... the first 999999999 times, that is. :)

Comment: D'oh!  i learned that long ago... thanks for a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 6):

[`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) might be the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

use an xml parser.